# Not able to see full Title text in android default dialog as its showing ellipsize at the start of text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Just i used default Android Alert Dialog to show 2 line description and message for it. when i run below code its showing ellipsize at the start of title text in android.

```
public void showDeleteConfirmationDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_document_title));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_document_message));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File file;
                    for (String scanImagePath : scanImageList) {
                        file = new File(scanImagePath);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            }).run();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_btn_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

and start ellipsize on title.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSI3n.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
textView.setMaxLines(2);
textView.setText(getString(R.string.dialog_document_title));

builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_document_message));
 builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_btn_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File file;
                    for (String scanImagePath : scanImageList) {
                        file = new File(scanImagePath);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            file.delete();
                        }
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            }).run();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_btn_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither using android.app.AlertDialog or android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog can i replicate your phenomenon.May be i can not help you.But you may need to change the method run() to start(),and usual we let the dialog's[image] message show the long words instead of title,title just setText("tips").(my english is very poor,please...)